# Convert JSON to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working on a Phone Directory app and I have a JSON in following format:

```
{
    "8541234567": "Peter James",
    "3473433347": "John Ham",
    "8446407343": "Rahul Desai"
}
```

How do I display it in `HTML` format with `Name` and `Phone Number` in the table header using `jQuery`?

I tried:

```
var data = JSON.parse(data); 
alert(data[0][0]);
```

but it showed a blank output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it resolved. I used jQuery .each

```
$.each(data, function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

iterate through your object using jquery `each()` . assuming index is phn no. and value is the name you want.
try this

```
var data={"8541234567":"Peter James","3473433347":"John Ham","8446407343":"Rahul Desai"}

$.each(data,function(i,v){
  alert('phn: '+ i);
  alert('name: '+ v);
})
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/kxz9j/)